# From where do we know that Yaakov has the spirit of prophecy when referred to as Yisroel?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, nevua-prophecy

The Torah frequently shifts in references to Yaakov. I have heard that it refers to him as Yisroel when he is experiencing prophecy, and as Yaakov when his prophetic abilities are lacking, as they were when Yosef was thought to be dead.  Where does this idea come from (e.g. mesorah or textual) and what source is the best to reference for this?

Comment: Yaakov has the spirit of prophecy because through the name, "Yisroel," which the malach and Hashem gave him, he rose to become a higher entity with additional powers.
First, we must notice that the Yisroel is a secret word containing the first letters of all of our forefathers and fore mothers. Look at the letters forming the name י ש ר א ל . The first letter Yood, stands for the two forefathers named, י צ ח ק and י ע ק ב. The second letter Seen, stands for the fore mother ש ר ה . The third letter Raysh, stands for the two fore mothers ר ח ל and ר ב ק ה . ...

Comment: ... The fourth letter Alef, stands for the forefather א ב ר ה ם . The fifth letter Lamed, stands for the fore mother ל א ה . So, the name of Yisroel carries much more weight (spiritual influence) than Yaakov.